# Angular - Loading data for a specific item with NGRX / Effects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, store, effects, ngrx

I have a page with a list of products. These products reside in the store and are managed by a `products` reducer. A `PRODUCTS.LOAD_ALL` action is dispatched, an effect catches it, does an API call and dispatches a `PRODUCTS.LOAD_ALL_SUCCESS` action which the `products` reducer uses to populate the store.

I now have another page which is to edit a specific product and I have some questions regarding the best place to load / store this product. Should I stick with effects and dispatch an action to eventually get it in the store. If so, would I reuse the `products` reducer with an `active` property or would I introduce a new `product` reducer to hold this specific product? Alternative, should I step away form effects at this point and just call the API from my container component and pass the product down to the necessary children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I stick with effects and dispatch an action to eventually get it in the store?

Yes.

#### Why?

Because that way all your components can keep relying on the store and valid data. - Whenever the user is done editing, the following data-flow should happen:

1. In your edit-component the used edits a copy of the product
2. User clicks "Save" (or it's saved on input.blur, ect..)
3. An action is dispatched with `PRODUCTS.SAVE_PRODUCT`
4. An effect will call a service-method to persist the new changes (rest-call, or localstorage, ect..)
5. When the persisting is successful -> the reducer gets an action with the new product-object and puts it into the store
6. All components that are currently subscribing to store-updates will be informed automatically

---

> If so, would I reuse the products reducer with an active property or would I introduce a new product reducer to hold this specific product?

If your products-array contains all the detail for all products already, I'd suggest to use the data from there - remember though: never edit store-data from the store directly, only work on copies (this can be enforced by using immutables, in case you are not doing that already)

---

> Alternative, should I step away form effects at this point and just call the API from my container component and pass the product down to the necessary children?

Heeell no... I mean.. technically yes, you could - but you would loose practically all the benefits that the ngrx-store brings regarding clean data-flows, data-integrity, ect...

Depending on the application(especially small ones) there are cases for sure where ngrx just mostly brings code-overhead and no real benefit - so there is no *"one perfect way for all cases"* - but I'd highly suggest **not** to go half way with a bunch of solutions that just messes up the code-base.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What are your thoughts to the following: once the success comes back from the persistence, instead of updating the store with the new object from memory, dispatching an action to reload the product list?

Comment: If you are lazy with coding, that should technically work - but the "clean" way would be to include the persisted product in the response of the persistence-call and emit some `PRODUCT_SAVE_SUCCESS` and have the reducer replace the old product in the array -> this should have the same result as reloading the whole list from scratch and should save server-resources as well

Comment: Again - technically all your suggestions are fine (I hope I don't come across as some ngrx-nazi ;-) ) - it's just a question on how _perfect_ you want your code to be - my personal rule of thumb is: if there are more than 2 ppl involved with the code: be religious about it, otherwise go with whatever is the least amount of effort but does not totally mess up the code-base.

Comment: I do always strive for perfection ah. We've had many a discussion about updating the store from memory / making another API call. It's good to hear what other people think about these "real world" problems.